# How can you re-enter Pilgrim's Path in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

(spoilers on Thieves guild)

I've beaten the mission where you go thru the twilight sanctum and return the skeleton key for some time now. I came back to the sanctum in hope of redoing pilgrim path, but the portal is in the way! I have been looking on google for an answer for some time now, but I only get results for people asking for the first time going thru. Has anyone found a way to do this? Any answer will be of help. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I've found a "flying" glitch, but it doesn't work well. It involves standing in the middle of a bucket, holding it, then jumping repeatedly. Does anyone know a better way of doing this/other flight glitches, since I could use this to go back up the hole I fell down to get to the skeleton key?

Answer (score 2):

You can't redo the [Pilgrim's Path](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Pilgrim%27s_Path) after the first time you do it during the quest.

However, since the reward for finishing the Pilgrim's Path is choosing a Nightingale power, I assume that your intention is changing your Nightingale power, which you *can* do.

Fast travel to the [Twilight Sepulcher](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight_Sepulcher). Enter [Ebonmere](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebonmere) portal to the Inner Sanctum. There, you can choose your power by standing on the appropriate platform:

> Crescent Moon Platform
>
> Standing on this platform grants the Nightingale Shadow ability, which allows the Nightingale Agent to turn invisible once a day for 120 seconds.
>
> Half Moon Platform
>
> Standing on this platform grants the Nightingale Subterfuge ability, which allows the Nightingale to cause all people and creatures within the area of effect to attack each other for 30 seconds, once a day.
>
> Full Moon Platform
>
> Standing on this platform grants the Nightingale Strife ability, which allows the Nightingale to shoot a pillar of dark energy into their victim, which causes them to absorb 100 points of health from them. It can only be used once a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's impossible to re enter after you've finished the main quest about the key.